# Соленые шутки

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Интересно, почему, когда мы хотим обозначить, что шутка имеет скабрезный оттенок, то говорим, что она соленая?
Если речь о специях вообще, то термин "соленая" относился бы, скорее, к остроте, а не к неприличности. Тогда почему же все-таки шутки "соленые"?
*Вроде такого вопроса тут не было - по крайней мере, поиск ничего не выдал.*

Answer (score 1):

Всего должно быть в меру: как соли в пище, так и юмора в шутке. Когда человек шутит, не зная меры, его шутки становятся, как перенасыщенная солью пища – неприятными – **солёными**.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, дело в "специфическом" юморе моряков.